# angular2: why window.location.href causes page refresh on Firefox but href don't

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox, typescript

I'm working with Angular2 and I have a method to download file...everything works fine but I was using an `<a>` and downloaded the files using `href='routetodownload'` I was asked to disable this link in some cases and then a decided to change the `<a>` by `<button>` (the link was working as button either way) and to do so, instead of using the `href` attribute, I've created a function.
**HTML**

```
<button (click)="download(url)">download</button>
```

**Typescript**

```
download(url) {
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

but this causes a strange behavior on firefox, when I click to download, the save dialog appears but behind it, the page refresh. When using `<a href='url'>` the page doesn't refresh when the save as dialog appears

This is happening only using Firefox...Edge and Chrome in both situation works fine.

I'm wondering why window.location.href causes autorefresh on Firefox.

If anyone have any idea about this, please let me

**UPDATE**

The problem, after all, was the `NG Live Development Server` (from angular-cli `ng serve` command)...I have no idea why this is happening only with Firefox. The thing is, my app is hosted on IIS and I have no refresh in my solution using with it.

I'll check later with guys from angular-cli team what can be this behavior...

Thank you all.

Regards

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I though the same thing but still don't understand why this isn't happening with anchor href...do you have any idea how to avoid this behavior?

Comment: @Pointy thanks but it didn't work. I don't even have a form is this page ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only happens on the local angular-cli live server because by default all routes get routed to the /index.html, which is the root of your application. Angular router doesn't find your file URL and just takes you to the default route.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this:

`<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>`

add the download attribute for better results.

Comment: The "download" thing is not supported in Safari, as far as I know.

Comment: Yeah its not supported by safari and I.E http://caniuse.com/#feat=download.   Not sure what would happen if you add _target="blank" and use that as a fallback.

Comment: As I put in my question, the download already works using `a+href` I just want to understand why using window.location.href refresh the page in Firefox

Comment: Weird I just tested you code in Firefox and it opens up the image (local and remote) in a full browser window and no page refreshing.

Comment: my url is an MVC action that returns the file...maybe a fisical address works in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` attempting to load another HTML page, but you are in an exceptional case.

You should replace it by :

```
download(url) {
    window.open(url);
}
```

Or try something like this :

```
download(url) {
    link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    ...
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Comment: I though about window.open but it will open a new tab in firefox...and if I press `cancel` on the `save as` dialog , I'll be in an empty tab...using "_self" give me the same behave as windows.location.href...I'll check if functional designers agree with the window.open solution...if anything works, I'll just use the <a> tag again...I wouldn't like but probably will be the only whay..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to disable your link is to use a Javascript to cancel the hyperlink activation event.

> Some events are specified as cancelable. For these events, the DOM implementation generally has a default action associated with the event. An example of this is a hyperlink in a web browser. When the user clicks on the hyperlink the default action is generally to active that hyperlink. Before processing these events, the implementation must check for event listeners registered to receive the event and dispatch the event to those listeners. These listeners then have the option of canceling the implementation's default action or allowing the default action to proceed. In the case of the hyperlink in the browser, canceling the action would have the result of not activating the hyperlink.

https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation

For example :

```
<a [attr.href]="isDisabled(link) ? null : 'link.href'"
   [class.disabled]="isDisabled(link)"
   (click)="!isDisabled(link)">
   {{ link.name}}
</a>
```

Comment: As I said in another comment and also in my question: my download works with `<a>` tag properly...I just decide to change by a button because it works like a button...and then I came across with this problem...I wasn't expecting this behavior...so, if I it's not possible to avoid this behavior, I'll use `<a>` tag again.. ;-)

Comment: So you could add the link programatically on button click. I give you an example (for code decoration) in my other answer...

Comment: the problem, after all was the `NG Live Development Server` use it by angular CLI...I don't know why it refresh the page only in Firefox. I don't even notice it was happening with `href` solution either. window.location.href works fine IIS and IIS express. Thanks.